# Inner join with like clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using inner join with the like clause ..

My tried sql is

```
SELECT tbl_songs.id    AS sid, 
       tbl_songs.name  AS sname, 
       tbl_albums.id   AS aid, 
       tbl_albums.name AS aname 
FROM   tbl_songs 
       INNER JOIN tbl_albums 
               ON tbl_songs.albums LIKE '%' + tbl_albums.name + '%';
```

Its showing me syntax error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ tbl_albums.name + '%'' at line 2
```

Please elaborate reason of syntax error.

Comment: Please be aware that using `LIKE` with a leading wildcard is bad for performance. Using it with joins is extremely bad for performance. You would be well advised to try to come up with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you have to form the clause using concat ...

```
...LIKE CONCAT('%',tbl_albums.name, '%');
```

there is no `+` operator like this in mysql

Comment: CONCAT in orace takes only two arguments: CONCAT(CONCAT('%',tbl_albums.name), '%');

Comment: thats correct, in this case one can use two concat functions (as my original answer was). however, then i saw that the question was for mysql specificall, so i adjusted it

Comment: CONCAT with MySQL takes several arguments. Seeing as how this question was tagged MySQL, it should be answered that way.

`CONCAT(str1,str2,...)`

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: Nice bro. Work like a charm. Saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use below format in oracle sql:
  SELECT tbl_songs.id    AS sid, 
           tbl_songs.name  AS sname, 
           tbl_albums.id   AS aid, 
           tbl_albums.name AS aname 
    FROM   tbl_songs 
           INNER JOIN tbl_albums 
                   ON tbl_songs.albums LIKE ('%'||tbl_albums.name||'%');
```

Answer (score -1):

An example of MySQL:

```
SELECT  tbl_songs.bus_name FROM tbl_songs , tbl_albums
WHERE tbl_songs.albums LIKE CONCAT('%',tbl_albums.name, '%');
```

Comment: What? Your answer is using entirely different tables, and you have no context for how this helps answer the question. (And to be honest, the additional "Check this out" text at the bottom makes it look like it was poorly copy-pasted from somewhere else)

Comment: What?? why can't we use entirely different tables, we have two tables  (bus , chm_master cm), cm is the alias of of chm_master. See this is just working correct for me. I don't understand what you exactly trying to reveal here. cm.bus_json is the json value, in which i'm trying to find the bus_name. What's wrong in that. frankly  you should clarify you concepts here.

Comment: The question uses `tbl_albums` and `tbl_songs` as tables. Your answer is using `bus` and `chm_master`.  That's what I mean when I say you're using different tables.  This might work if you explained how it answers the question, but as is, it's just a block of code that has no context.

Comment: Now you can see the tbl_songs's albums having relationship with tbl_albums. Are you happy now?

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.