# like keyword in inner join sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I am facing some strange issue on using `like` keyword with `inner join` in sqlite query.

I want to fetch records on category_code, as category_code are saved in different string format in both tables. So I am writing below query but no output.

```
select categories.category_code, services.* from categories join services on services.category_code like '%' + categories.category_code + '%' where services.country_code like '%IN%'
```

[image: Categories table]

[image: Services table]

any advise please?

Comment: this: like '%' + categories.category_code + '%'... I'd try so: like % + categories.category_code + %

Comment: try this: `select categories.category_code, services.* from categories join services on services.category_code like '%"+ categories.category_code+ "%' and where services.country_code like '%IN%'`

Comment: -Tobor No, it says 'Likely SQL syntax error'

Comment: - MD, Inner is optional keyword but I tried with Inner keyword but result.

Comment: @YousufQureshi post your logcat

Comment: @MD I am running query in SQLite Manager(Firefox plugin) for now.

Comment: but here error is not about like but i think u r Query is totally wrong way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46837/discussion-between-yousuf-qureshi-and-m-d)

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003165/inner-join-with-like-clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQLite, the + operator is a mathematical add, not a string concatenator (like it is in other RDBMS such as SQL Server). For string concatenation in SQLite, use a double pipe ||.

```
select categories.category_code, services.*
from categories join services
  on services.category_code like '%' || categories.category_code || '%'
where services.country_code like '%IN%'
```